# How load to Django Paginator Page (next/ previous)?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Hy,
i followed a tutorial for a multiple model search and it worked. now i want to paginate the output. But how can i load my paginator page (next/ previous) data into my template? So far if i push **next** i get an error.

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView
from django.views.generic import View
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db.models import Q
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from itertools import chain

# --- Import Models
from datainput.models import Animal
from datainput.models import Farmer

<....>

class SearchView(ListView):
    template_name = 'farmapi/searchview.html'
    paginate_by = 2
    count = 0

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['count'] = self.count or 0
        context['query'] = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        request = self.request
        query = request.GET.get('q', None)

        if query is not None:
            farmer_results        = Farmer.objects.search(query)
            animal_results      = Animal.objects.search(query)


        # combine querysets 
            queryset_chain = chain(
                    farmer_results,
                    animal_results
            )        
            qs = sorted(queryset_chain, 
                    key=lambda instance: instance.pk, 
                    reverse=True)
            self.count = len(qs) # since qs is actually a list
            return qs

        return Farmer.objects.none() # just an empty queryset as default
```

**template.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load class_name %}
{% load static %}

{% block custom_css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/home_styles.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div style="height: 10px;">
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-4 offset-md-8">
            <form method='GET' class='' action='.'>
                <div class="input-group form-group-no-border mx-auto" style="margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 32px;">
                    <span class="input-group-addon cfe-nav" style='color:#000'>
                        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" name="q" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Press enter to search" class="form-control cfe-nav mt-0 py-3" placeholder="Search..." value="" style="" data-original-title="" title="" autofocus="autofocus">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="height: 10px;">
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 offset-md-4">
            {% for object in object_list %}
            {% with object|class_name as klass %}
            {% if klass == 'Farmer' %}
            <div class='row'>
                Farmer: <a href='{{ object.get_absolute_url }}'> {{ object.first_name }} {{ object.last_name }}</a>
            </div>
            {% elif klass == 'Animal' %}
            <div class='row'>
                Animal: <a href='{{ object.get_absolute_url }}'> {{ object.name }} {{ object.species }}</a>
            </div>
            {% else %}
            <div class='row'>
                <a href='{{ object.get_absolute_url }}'>{{ object }} | {{ object|class_name }}</a>
            </div>
            {% endif %}

            {% endwith %}

            {% empty %}

            {% endfor %}
            <div style="height: 10px;">
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
                <results>{{ count }} results for <b>{{ query }}</b></results>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Pagniator Data -->
    <div class="paginator">
        <span class="step-links">

            <span class="current">
                Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
            </span>

            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
            {% endif %}



            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
            {% endif %}

        </span>
    </div>

</div>
    {% endblock %}
```

if i my template shows me for instance **"4 Results for xyz"**  and **"Page 1 of 2"** and i push **next** or **last** Page, then i get this Error Message:

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request URL:
>     http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/searchview/?page=2 Raised by:
>     farmapi.views.SearchView
>
> Invalid page (2): That page contains no results

So as far as i understand i have to explicit paginate the return of my queryset so that the paginator will put it into? Or did i miss to set a request for the paginator?

Comment: you need to create paginator object in in your view then send it to template as a dict likt this:

Comment: {'paginator': paginator} . It looks like you are not creating paginator object itself in your view

Comment: @chiragsoni no, the ListView will do that.

Comment: @chirag soni could you specify {'paginator': paginator} / paginator object? where should i put it? I guess also that that something is missing. On the other hand, if there is no paginator object, why django than reacts to  {% if is_paginated %} or display me how many pages (1 of 2 for instance) my results/search list has? If it has nothing to interpreter (Page objects) should not work or?

Answer (score 0):

I also use a paginator where the number of items per page can be defined by the user. I added following method:

```
def get_paginate_by(self, queryset):
    limit = int(self.request.POST.get('limit', 25))

    return limit
```

In the template it looks like:

```
{% if is_paginated %}
     {{ page_obj|render_paginator }}
{% endif %}
```

where render_paginator a template tag is.
In your template call a url like: your_url?page=2

Comment: I search some Attributes or Method in my **ListView** for my paginator so that the  Paginator Page will update, when i push "next page". I don´t want to "limit" the paginator outcome.

Comment: Ok, I just showed a method to do it differently than @chirag proposed. But the page variable in the querystring is enough. Look also here https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/03/how-to-paginate-with-django.html

Comment: "page variable in the querystring" could you add this do your answer ?